# Separating a compound sentence with multiple subjects into multiple sentences with one subject each?

Tags: nlp

Is there a way to separate a compound sentence with multiple subjects like:

- I am a human, and you are a human. => I am a human. You are a human.
- The dog sometimes eats cheese, and it is a labrador. => The dog sometimes eats cheese. It is a labrador.

I was thinking about separating it using a parse tree and identifying multiple subjects, but I'm not sure of how to create an algorithm that will do this generally and reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to identify *connective* and its type(*implicit/explicit connective*) and use *constituency parse tree* of sentence to identify arguments of the connective.

Examples:

**(1) I am a human and you are a human.**

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP (PRP I))
      (VP (VBP am)
        (NP (DT a) (NN human))))
    (CC and)
    (S
      (NP (PRP you))
      (VP (VBP are)
        (NP (DT a) (NN human))))
    (. .)))
```

=> Here you can see that **S -> S CC S**. Which means both arguments connected using CC are sentences itself. So you can directly split them from CC.

=> You will get 2 sentences.

1) I am a human 2) you are a human

**(2) John went to Hotel and had lunch.**

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP John))
    (VP
      (VP (VBD went)
        (PP (TO to)
          (NP (NNP Hotel))))
      (CC and)
      (VP (VBD had)
        (NP (NN lunch))))
    (. .)))
```

=> Here, **VP -> VP CC VP**, means connective is used to connect two verb groups and they have shared subject. So you can use same subject in both sentences and add one VP.

=> The result will be,

1) John went to Hotel 2) John had lunch

**(3) John ate apple and banana. John and Mike ate apple.**

```
(ROOT              #John ate apple and banana.
  (S
    (NP (NNP John))
    (VP (VBD ate)
      (NP (NN apple)
        (CC and)
        (NN banana)))
    (. .)))

(ROOT              #John and Mike ate apple.
  (S
    (NP (NNP John)
      (CC and)
      (NNP Mike))
    (VP (VBD ate)
      (NP (NN apple)))
    (. .)))
```

=> Here, **NP -> NN CC NN** and **NP-> NNP CC NNP** which means CC connects two NNs/NNPs both can be used separately as well. So you can split these NNs/NNPs.

=> You will get sentences like,

1) John ate apple 2) John ate banana   [and]

1) John at apple 2) Mike ate apple

Answer (score 0):

you've to work on it.you can use POStagger and Parse tree for this.

[here](http://harmeetsingh13.blogspot.in/2013/05/search-noun-adjectives-verbs-from-text.html)'s how you extract nouns,adjective and verbs using [opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html)

It's easy to setup and use, you can follow this [blog](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/opennlp-tutorial.html)

now that you know how to extract parts of a sentence using POS, it must be easier to achieve what you want.

hope this helps!